# Facing connectionError in django while using ElasticSearch with docker

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, elasticsearch

I am trying to load instances from my django model to the elasticsearch server but i get the error:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f1c8cffbc18>: 
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -8] Servname not supported for ai_socktype) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f1c8cffbc18>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -8] Servname not supported for ai_socktype)
```

I have established an instance of elasticsearch server using docker on my localhost on port 9200 using command:

```
docker run -d -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node"  docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.0.0
```

I am able to access the server using the curl/localhost, but I get the error above.

Comment: You need to create a docker network or use `--net=host` in docker run sentence

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit? I did include the "--net=host" in the docker run sentence but it gives the same error.

Comment: If `--net=host` is not working, it's not an issue related to docker network sharing. So, maybe it's an ElasticSearch issue, not docker issue. Try to have a look at /etc/hosts inside and outside docker. Maybe `Servname` is not defined